# When and where to call webservice from GUI

Tags: c#, wpf

We have an application that can be used to view the current quantity of products available for sale. The user has a GUI to create filters, for example, all black products of at least 1kg. When the user changes the filter, a service call with the filter descriptions is made and the results are shown in charts. The service call is very slow, say 5 seconds. This in itself it not a problem.

The problem lies in changing the filters. What, in the user interface code, is the right place to make the call to the webservice.
I could place a CallWebService() line in all button_pressed and lost_focus events. This does not feel right somehow.
I could also register to the collection_changed and property_changed events in the data model and call the webservice there. This results in several calls when all elements from list are removed.
We currently have a controller class in between that is called from the GUI (button_press events etc.) but inside the controller several methods call each other wich has double service calls as a result.

We use a data model, a view and a controller in combination with WPF and databinding However, we have had problems like these in other applications and I am wondering what the right place/event is to place the call to the webservice. I would like to avoid asynchronous programming and in my perception my problem has nothing to do with asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest call service when user stop entering filter with some delay (say 5 seconds or even less).

Also if you want avoid ui frezing you can use [Background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class for web service calls(and while thread will work show progress image for the user).

Comment: Building a delay does not feel like the right way to prevent double updates. I am looking for a way to prevent them, not mask them.

Answer (score 0):

You should different between triggering a web service call from actually making the call. For example, you can trigger the call on any change mechanism (for example - data model changes or UI events like button press). A trigger would (re)start the timer to make the service call. Key is to restarting the existing timer every time event is arrived. By choosing a good value for timer say 1-2 seconds, you can actual make service call when there is pause in user's action.

Comment: The problem is not the user triggering multiple updates but the software triggering the webservice multiple times because of bindings that update and code that responds to the new data and therefore triggering another service call. That is why I am wondering at what place other people place those service calls.

Comment: @Raymond, the point still applies - even if code triggers multiple web service calls, only one call would be made over specified duration. That way, you can have automatic trigger points and still have reasonable number of web service calls.

Comment: I disagree. The timer adds an extra delay for the user and if several service calls are made to the server the total time for the last service call will be longer because other calls are busy too.

Comment: @Raymond, idea is actually to reduce number of service calls to decrease server load. If aim is to make only one service call with consolidated changes then it is not possible via automatic triggers - in general, your data model will accumulate changes but then update call would be made explicitly. Yet another approach is to keep accumulating changes and commit them periodically. And yet another approach is to make multiple calls with carrying only change sets. Note all these make sense in case of update scenarios but its my impression that u r talking about querying data and not updating it.